# Workaround memory leak in shared object

Tags: python, memory-leaks, shared-libraries

In my Python code I use a third party shared object, a `.so` file, which I suspect to contains a memory leak.

During the run of my program I have a loop where I repeatedly call functions of the shared object. While the programm is running I can see in `htop`, that the memory usage is steadily increasing. When the RAM is full, the programm crashes with the terminal output `killed`. My assumption is, that if the memory leak is produced by the shared object, because otherwise Python would raise an `Exception.MemoryError`.

I tried using [`reload(modul_name)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)  followed by a `gc.collect()` but it did not free the memory according to `htop`.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether there are any object destruction/deallocation functions provided by the library so that clients can cause the memory to be freed.

See if you can identify whether it is a single function that causes the apparent leak, and then try to avoid calling that function.

Other than that, unless you have the shared library's source code or the maintainer's ear, there's not much that you can do.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise. Is there another way to force python to drop and reload a so library or is this not possible, or just not working it that case here? I will try to get a hold of the source code.

Comment: And what about the other assumptions. Do you think they are correct?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary fix you can use a decorator to run your function in a sperate process, but eventually you will need to fix the underlying leak.

```
import multiprocessing
def memory_leak(func):
  def conn_func(conn, *args, **kwargs):
    conn.send(func(*args, **kwargs))
    conn.close()

  def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
    parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=conn_func, args=[child_conn]+list(args), kwargs=kwargs)
    p.start()
    result = parent_conn.recv()
    p.join()
    return result

  return new_function
```